# Django: tracking all the database changes with values

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have to implement an application in django which will track all the changes in the database with the previous values,current value,action,date,time, user(who performed the changes) etc.

Is there any application/module available in python or django which can perform these actions with may be after some changes. I have seen "fullhistory" app in Django but it does not fits into the requirement.

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django-reversion http://github.com/etianen/django-reversion could be an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

fullhistory seems to do most of what you want - what part of the requirement does it not fulfil? It might be easier to enhance fullhistory.

Another option is to do it at the database level, if your database supports logging at that level.

Comment: As the document suggests, fullhistory holds the information for the actions outside the admin panel. Though I have seen the code and not tested it.